# XSLT1, Muenchian grouping, listing the grouped nodes in a foreach loop

Tags: foreach, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping, muenchian-grouping

Given the xml code

```
<z>
<f hit="1">
<g>hola1</g>
</f>
<f hit="2">
<g>hola2</g>
</f>
<f hit="3">
<g>hola1</g>
</f>
</z>
```

I want to have the xml output

```
<z>
hola1
hola2
</z>
```

using xslt1. Then, an easy solution would be the muenchian grouping

```
<xsl:key name="thisone" match="/z/f/g" use="." />
<z>
<xsl:for-each select="/z/f[generate-id(g)=generate-id(key('thisone',g)[1])]">
<xsl:value-of select="g" />
</xsl:for-each>
</z>
```

However, when I apply this to a large dataset, the system (firefox) keeps thinking forever. I assume that this is due to the really large dataset. However, the number of different values of "g" is really low.

My question is: Is there any way to do a for-each loop of the nodes of the Muenchian grouping? Something like

```
<xsl:for-each select="nodes_of_key('thisone')">
```

That would avoid comparing all the values of all the "g" nodes, which takes forever?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One doesn't need any `<xsl:for-each>` instruction to solve this problem** (and this instruction is best avoided):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFByG" match="f" use="g"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <z>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
     </z>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="f[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kFByG',g)[1])]">
     <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="g"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<z>
    <f hit="1">
        <g>hola1</g>
    </f>
    <f hit="2">
        <g>hola2</g>
    </f>
    <f hit="3">
        <g>hola1</g>
    </f>
</z>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<z>
hola1
hola2
</z>
```

Comment: Yes, but the same comparison is used. My problem is that this is working when I have a small file to process, but when this file is larger then the browser keeps processing forever.

Therefore my question, if there is any way to avoid to compare all the nodes and just go through the ones that are "stored" in the xsl:key (if such thing is possible)

Comment: @Gerard, This is a key-based solution and it is orders of magnitude faster (close to O(1)) than comparing a value with all other values (O(N^2)).

Comment: @Gerard, Going through "all the nodes" is linear -- it is really fast, probably subsecond for even hundred MB size.

Comment: But then, what can I do? I understand (am I wrong?) that the foreach instruction is not recommended due to the style (templates have more sense in xslt), but if it does not have any consequences in efficiency (am I wrong?), then the key-based comparison is taking forever in a 7Mb file of 20.000 entries (each entry will become a node to compare). What could I do?

Comment: @Gerard, This has nothing to do with whether or not `xsl:for-each` is used. A 7MB file can be processed in a fraction of a second -- this isn't at all big file. Several hundred MBs can be processed in 2-3 seconds. If your transformation takes so long, there is some other issue -- not the Muenchian grouping. The issue may not evewn have to do with the XSLT transformation at all. I have seen cases where a huge table is generated: the transformation takes less than a second, but the browser takes forever to format the table for display. There are cures for this (some style?) that I don't remember

Comment: @Gerard, For example, don't generate one huge table, but generate several tables (split the big table into a dozen smaller ones). Or don't generate a table at all, but generate a sequence of paragraphs.

Comment: @Gerard, I just made an experiment. Muenchian grouping of 20000 elements by value took 237 milliseconds -- that is about one fifth of a second.

Comment: @Gerard, See for example this: http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol4/load_no19.htm

Comment: Thanks Dimitre (I have missed the last messages and I read them now). Sometimes I am too focused in using xslt for everything. I have believed you in the sense that xslt was not the responsible but firefox. Then, since I am creating the xml file with javascript, I have just create a group of nodes with the unique names in xml, so then xslt can easily access to this "array" without having to think. And then firefox is just working fast. An easy workaround I guess :)

Comment: @Gerard, You are welcome. And you don't need to "believe" me. Just make an experiment (as I did) and perform the transformation separately from the browser, and see how long it takes. If the transformation involves only Muenchian grouping, the time it takes will be less than a second.